# open() in __del__ function causing LookupError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to dump some data to json when my class gets destroyed, but when I try to open a file I get an error:

`LookupError: unknown encoding: ascii`

The del function is just:

```
logs_file = open('/tmp/log.json', 'w')
json.dump(data, logs_file)
logs_file.close()
```

with the error on the open line.

I assume something important is being unloaded before my del code runs. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: What, exactly, is causing `__del__` to be invoked in the first place?

Comment: Did you try using `encoding` attribute and setting it accordingly to your file?

Comment: Note, too, that there is no guarantee that your `__del__` method will be invoked *at all* when your program exits, so it's generally not a good idea to put code that you depend on running there. If you want to guarantee that `data` gets written to a log file before program exit, use the `atexit` module.

Comment: @chepner I think this will work, thank you!